# Remove Gatsby/Gatsby-Cli - previously installed with brew

Tags: homebrew, gatsby

I want to remove my global version of gatsby from my M2 Mac.

When I do this:

```
gatsby -v
Gatsby CLI version: 5.0.0
```

Then I do:

```
where gatsby
/opt/homebrew/bin/gatsby
```

Then I do:

```
brew remove gatsby
Error: No available formula with the name "gatsby". Did you mean gatsby-cli?
```

```
brew remove gatsby-cli
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gatsby-cli
```

What's going on here? It looks like gatsby has been installed with brew, but how can I remove it? Since `where gatsby` shows a homebrew path, I suppose it has been installed via brew. `/opt/homebrew/bin/gatsby` is a link to `/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/cli.js`. Should I just delete the link and the source file inside `node_modules` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe installed with global npm/yarn package.

**npm**:

`> npm uninstall -g gatsby`

**yarn**

`> yarn global remove gastby`